# Problema CSS con background distinto en diferentes elementos

Tags: html, css, css3, wordpress

Buen día compañeros, que pena la molestia. Estoy tratando de hacer lo siguiente.
[image: Lo que debo hacer]

Ya he hecho varias cosas, solo me hace falta cambiar el background-color, he intentado con nth-child pero no me sirve. Lo único que he hecho es que me aparece el color en todos los elementos y yo quiero elegir un color por cada uno de los elementos.

[image: Esto es lo que tengo hecho pero no es lo que debo hacer]

Me podrían ayudar. Este es el código que tengo en HTML con PHP

```
<section class="historias">
<div>
    <ul class="listado-historias">
        <?php 
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'cooperativas',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'posts_per_page' => 30
            );
            $historias = new WP_Query($args);
            while($historias->have_posts()): $historias->the_post();
        ?>
        <li class="historia">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <div class="contenido text-center">
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">+ INFORMACIÓN</a>
            </div>
        </li>

        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Y en el CSS tengo lo siguiente:

```
.listado-historias {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.listado-historias li {
    flex: 0 0 calc(33.333%);
    position: relative;
}
.historia .contenido{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    color: var(--blanco);
}
```

Agradecería su ayuda, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo del `nth-child` sí que funciona pero tu lo aplicas al `.contenido` y de contenido tienes solo uno en cada `.historia`. La solución es utilizar `.historia:nth-child(..` porque de historias tienes varias.

```css
.listado-historias {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border:solid;
    padding:0;
}
.listado-historias li {
    list-style:none;
    flex: 0 1 30%;
    border:solid;
}
.historia{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    color: white;
    padding:1em;
}

.historia:nth-child(2){background-color: red;}
.historia:nth-child(3){background-color: skyblue;}

h3{margin-top:0;}
```

```html
<section class="historias">
<div>
    <ul class="listado-historias">

        <li class="historia">
            <div class="contenido text-center">
                <h3>the_title</h3>
                <p>the_content</p>

                <a href="#">INFORMACIÓN</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="historia">
            <div class="contenido text-center">
                <h3>the_title</h3>
                <p>the_content</p>

                <a href="#">INFORMACIÓN</a>
            </div>
        </li>
              <li class="historia">
            <div class="contenido text-center">
                <h3>the_title</h3>
                <p>the_content</p>

                <a href="#">INFORMACIÓN</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### Actualización:

El OP comenta:

> El problema se basa en que debo colocar esos colores con transparencia por encima de la imagen y la verdad no esta dando

En CSS puedes fácilmente utilizar varias imágenes de fondo de esta manera:

```css
div{width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid silver;
    background:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.5), rgba(0,0,0,.5)), url(https://assets.codepen.io/222579/darwin300.jpg) center/cover;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

En el ejemplo anterior la primera imagen es la transparencia - un gradiente lineal. A continuación después de una coma aparece la imagen del perro. El orden de apilamiento es al revés. Puedes utilizar algo así en lugar de background-color

Comment: Buen día, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. El problema se basa en que debo colocar esos colores con transparencia por encima de la imagen y la verdad no esta dando.

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta. Por favor echale una mirada